# Name a series of files to their enclosing directory name in BASH

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a large series of files that were extracted by an app with a weird naming structure.

Each file is named "streamvideo 1.flv", enclosed in a folder named "video" enclosed by a second folder with the name that I want to use.

As in `4607/video/streamvideo 1.flv`.  What I want is to loop through all of these and rename streamvideo 1.flv after the numbered folder.  So, using my example, rename this instance to `4607.flv`

There are many:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
cd path/to/top/directory
for dir in */
do
    mv "$dir/video/streamvideo 1.flv" "${dir%%/}.flv"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with a little perl program:

```
for (<*>) {rename "$_/video/streamvideo 1.flv", "$_.flv";}
```

Answer (score 0):

find + mv

```
find * -type f -name "*.flv" |while read -r line; do mv "$line" "${line%%/*}.flv"; done
```